# Maven JUnit Test Case NoClassDefFoundException on Test class

Tags: junit, junit4, noclassdeffounderror, parameterized, surefire

I have a parameterized test case, just like a bunch of other test cases I have in the testing suite, that I have been trying to add the them.

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.example.Event;
import com.example.LocalStorage;
import com.example.TimeMachine;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TimeMachineEventEndTimeTest {

    public TimeMachineEventEndTimeTest(Event event, String end_time) {
        _event = event;
        _end_time = end_time;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            { _UNSCHEDULED, "" },
            { _NOON_FOR_1_HOUR, "13:00" },
            { _NOON_FOR_HALF_HOUR, "12:30" },
            { _MIDNIGHT_FOR_1_HOUR, "1:00" },
            { _MIDNIGHT_FOR_HALF_HOUR, "0:30" },
            { _MIDNIGHT_FOR_12_HOUR, "12:00" }
        });
    }

    @Before
    public void initialize() throws Exception {
        _time_machine = new _TimeMachine();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEndTimeForEvent() throws Exception {
        assertThat(_time_machine.endTimeForEvent(_event)).isEqualTo(_end_time);
    }

    private TimeMachine _time_machine;
    private final Event _event;
    private final String _end_time;
    private static final Gson _gson = new _GsonProvider(mock(LocalStorage.class)).gson();
    private static final Event _UNSCHEDULED = _gson.fromJson("{}", Event.class);
    private static final Event _NOON_FOR_1_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
        "      \"starttime\" : \"12:00\",\n" +
        "      \"duration\" : \"60\",\n" +
        "    }", Event.class);
    private static final Event _NOON_FOR_HALF_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
        "      \"starttime\" : \"12:00\",\n" +
        "      \"duration\" : \"30\",\n" +
        "    }", Event.class);
    private static final Event _MIDNIGHT_FOR_1_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
        "      \"starttime\" : \"0:00\",\n" +
        "      \"duration\" : \"60\",\n" +
        "    }", Event.class);
    private static final Event _MIDNIGHT_FOR_HALF_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
        "      \"starttime\" : \"0:00\",\n" +
        "      \"duration\" : \"30\",\n" +
        "    }", Event.class);
    private static final Event _MIDNIGHT_FOR_12_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
        "      \"starttime\" : \"0:00\",\n" +
        "      \"duration\" : \"360\",\n" +
        "    }", Event.class);
}
```

I have a few test cases with nearly identical structure that test different methods in the same directory and package. All my other tests run and pass 100% except this test case throws the this stack trace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.example.TimeMachineEventEndTimeTest
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SmartStackTraceParser.getClass(SmartStackTraceParser.java:63)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SmartStackTraceParser.(SmartStackTraceParser.java:53)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4StackTraceWriter.smartTrimmedStackTrace(JUnit4StackTraceWriter.java:72)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.encode(ForkingRunListener.java:328)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.encode(ForkingRunListener.java:312)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.toString(ForkingRunListener.java:258)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkingRunListener.testError(ForkingRunListener.java:131)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4RunListener.testFailure(JUnit4RunListener.java:111)
>       at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$4.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:100)
>       at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:41)
>       at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFailure(RunNotifier.java:97)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ErrorReportingRunner.runCause(ErrorReportingRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ErrorReportingRunner.run(ErrorReportingRunner.java:34)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else runs into a similar problem, it seems that for me it was my last few lines where I create some `Event`s. They had a small error in the JSON, which must cause `Gson` to error when constructing them.

```
 private static final Event _NOON_FOR_1_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
    "      \"starttime\" : \"12:00\",\n" +
    "      \"duration\" : \"60\"\n" +
    "    }", Event.class);
private static final Event _NOON_FOR_HALF_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
    "      \"starttime\" : \"12:00\",\n" +
    "      \"duration\" : \"30\"\n" +
    "    }", Event.class);
private static final Event _MIDNIGHT_FOR_1_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
    "      \"starttime\" : \"0:00\",\n" +
    "      \"duration\" : \"60\"\n" +
    "    }", Event.class);
private static final Event _MIDNIGHT_FOR_HALF_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
    "      \"starttime\" : \"0:00\",\n" +
    "      \"duration\" : \"30\"\n" +
    "    }", Event.class);
private static final Event _MIDNIGHT_FOR_12_HOUR = _gson.fromJson("{\n" +
    "      \"starttime\" : \"0:00\",\n" +
    "      \"duration\" : \"360\"\n" +
    "    }", Event.class);
```

The correction was to remove the "," after the "duration" values. It seems that the stacktrace was extremely cryptic and pretty misleading, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you run the test from your IDE? It looks like the stacktrace is misleading because of https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-962

It would be helpful, if you could provide a runnable gist, which reproduces the problem.

Comment: This is from Android Studio IDE. The code I shared is 100% of the code that is causing the problem. I'm unsure what you are asking for.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a complete project, where I could call mvn test.

Comment: I found what the misleading stacktrace meant to tell me about, thanks for trying.